# Convert a static library ".a" into Binding Library

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, objective-sharpie

I tried to use sharpies to convert a library `.a` into Binding Library but I have some error. The command that I have executed is:

```
sharpie bind -v -output=[...] --namespace=[...] --sdk=iphoneos11.0 lib.a
```

and the errors returned are:

> Error: unable to handle compilation, expected exactly one compiler job
>   in '' Error while processing
>   /Users/federicopieri/Desktop/GPDL/libMSSUniversal.a.
>
> Done. Exiting with error code 1. error: Clang failed to parse input
>   and exited with code 1

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You need to provide the header files to the library, not the static library itself  : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-sharpie/examples/advanced/

Comment: Can I extract the header file from static library?

Comment: No, need the header(s).

Comment: I'll ask the header file. THX

Comment: With the header files I have solved. THX